# How to detect top level bot framework dialog in a cancel scorable

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using a cancel scorable to trap the keywords quit and cancel and i use Task.Fail to fail the current dialog. The sample uses Task.Reset but that unwinds the entire stack which is not desirable in a multi level stack.

So Task.Fail works fine, I throw a OperationCanceledException and swallow that in the calling dialog however my issue is if i fail the top level dialog then my bot crashes.

How can i tell if i am at the top of the stack from the scorable (in which case i will ignore the message) or alternatively is there a better way to handle cancelling a single dialog?

Note that i see there is a Frames collection thats passed, I thought perhaps that could help but at the top level thats set to 4 and not 0 as i would expect, I am not sure if thats a reliable source?

Here is my instantiation of the root dialog

```
    internal static IDialog<object> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => new LuisDialogHome())
            .Do(async (context, dialog) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await dialog;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync($"Error from home dialog: {e.Message}");
                }
            });
    }

    protected override async Task PostAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // This will unwind the entire stack and take you right back to the top which we dont want so Fail the task instead to undo one layer
        //            this.task.Reset();
        this.task.Fail(new OperationCanceledException($"Cancelled"));
    }
```

And my cancelable issues task.Fail which results in the above exception handler being called and the 'Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.' message being sent to the user.

Comment: Can you post the bot code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, I made a scorable for the word "cancel"  this way from any point in the conversation you can start over.  [Also here is a good simple video to watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnU3lPHhv88)

```
    namespace PizzaBot.Dialogs
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Scorables.Internals;

    public class CancelScorable : ScorableBase<IActivity, string, double>
    {
        private readonly IDialogTask task;

        public CancelScorable(IDialogTask task)
        {
            SetField.NotNull(out this.task, nameof(task), task);
        }

        protected override async Task<string> PrepareAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var message = activity as IMessageActivity;

            if (message != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Text))
            {
                if (message.Text.Equals("cancel", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return message.Text;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected override bool HasScore(IActivity item, string state)
        {
            return state != null;
        }

        protected override double GetScore(IActivity item, string state)
        {
            return 1.0;
        }

        protected override async Task PostAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
        {
            this.task.Reset();
        }

        protected override Task DoneAsync(IActivity item, string state, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

then in my message controller i built a special case to handle it where `await SendGetStarted(iActivity, activity);` just starts the bot from the beginning:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{

    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {               
        try
        {
           await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog(activity.ChannelId));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IActivity iActivity = activity as IActivity;
            await SendGetStarted(iActivity, activity);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    if (activity.Text == "cancel")
    {
        IActivity iActivity = activity as IActivity;
        await SendGetStarted(iActivity, activity);
    }
    var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

you also nneed to add something like this to your Golbal.asax

```
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<CancelScorable>()
            .As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);`
```

Comment: This works however you get into a loop if the conversation continually throws so have to cater for that situation. I didnt end up using this because of that reason. I (somewhat hacked) use the Frames count of the task and if its <= 2 then, at least currently, it indicates you are at the top